# how to create row number as per partitioning on same column but for distinct values?

Tags: sql

I have 6 columns to be selected to design a report .There are duplicate records that may come because of columns i selected. I used row number ,but it is giving numbers 1 to 25 if have 25 records . What i would like to see is 1,2 if i have 2 records on my name and 1 as row number if i have only one record .

Example Table :

```
Name City         Age Teamsworked rownumber
X1   Bengaluru     26   it,sales     1
X1   Bengaluru     26    prosales    2
X2   Chennai       30    Finance     3
X3   Hyd           32    sales       4
```

I want row number to be grouped by Name and generate number like 1,2,1,1 in this case

Comment: What is the SQL vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below method .

Use Function : ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name order by Name)

You should be able to see the results in the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `partition by`:

```
row_number() over (partition by name, order by teamsworked) as rownumber
```